# Variable in header file not declared in scope

Tags: c++, scope, sdl, header-files

I'm attempting to make a simple game, I have my main .cpp file which includes a header file (let's call it A) which includes all the other header files (let's call them B). In one of those B header files I have included the A file to access the `programRunning` boolean which is defined in it. None of the B header files, despite including the A file which defines the variable, seem to be able to use it. I am really confused by this and would really appreciate some help. Below is the code I have used:

pong_header.h (the A header file as described above)

```
#ifndef PONG_HEADER_H
#define PONG_HEADER_H

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pong_graphics.h"
#include "pong_core.h"
#include "pong_entity.h"
#include "pong_event.h"

bool programRunning;

#endif
```

pong_event.h (one of the B header files)

```
#ifndef PONG_EVENT_H
#define PONG_EVENT_H

#include "pong_header.h"


void Pong_handleEvents(SDL_Event event)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            programRunning = true;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym):
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                programRunning = false;
                break;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        Pong_handleEntityEvents(event)
    }
}
```

The other B files access `programRunning` in the same way.

The exact error Code::Blocks gives me is as follows
`Pong\pong_event.h|20|error: 'programRunning' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: What you have posted should work. I suspect what you are describing and what actually happens is slightly different?

Comment: Make it extern bool programRunning; and have that in a source, too. (bool running). Do not forget to decorate it with import/export if it is a dlll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `pong_header.h` includes `pong_event.h` *before* it declares `programRunning`, so when `pong_header.h` tries to include `pong_event.h`, the include guards prevent it. The fix is to simply move the `bool programRunning` declaration to the top of `pong_event.h`.

Now, this will result in another issue - every `.cpp` file that includes any of these headers will get their own copy of `programRunning`, which will either cause a link error (multiple definition of `programRunning`), or it *will* compile, but won't run the way you expect.

What you want to do is declare it as *extern*, i.e.

```
extern bool programRunning;
```

Then, in *one* of your `.cpp` files (preferrably whichever has `int main`), you actually declare it (i.e. *without* `extern`):

```
bool programRunning;
```